# Drupal 7 node body content missing from search results

Tags: 7, nodes, search, cron

I am having an issue where my Drupal 7 Search (Custom search installed and enabled) isn't returning all of the results I'd expect it to.

**Here is some background...**

- I'm running Drupal 7 on this site.
- I have roughly 10 content types, but the search only returns 2 content types – `work` and `blog`.
- I am using the core `search module` along with drupal `custom search module`.

**The Issue:**

When I perform a search I am presented with a selection of results from both `work` and `blog` content types. However, the issue is while the `blog` content type produces the expected results pulling from keywords in both the node titles as well as the nodes body content, the `work` content type only returns results where the keyword is found in the node title.

**Attempted fixes:**

- I have confirmed that the site is 100% indexed. Just in case I have re-built the index.
- I went to the `Custom Search Module` settings to confirm that `-Any-` is being used in the `-Any content type-` text field. In addition, in the `Content exclusion` area I've made sure both the `blog` and `work` content types were left unchecked.
- I have confirmed that the `Minimum word length to index` is at 3. My searched words are above 5.
- And lastly, two thoughts I didn't know played into the search results, but were worth looking into are the `Manage Display` settings for both content types under their `Search index` and `Search result highlighting input` tabs. Both of which seem to be identical. So I assume wth my limited knowledge of Drupal's configurations isn't really vital to this issue.

I'm still trying other suggestions found here in StackOverflow and will update this as I come across new options to try as attempted fixes.

If anyone has come across this matter and can lead their considerable knowledge on it, that too is always appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to resolve this issue through a combination the following efforts.

- Under both `content types` and added in new fields to `search index` and `search results highlighting input`.
- Under `Administrator/Configuration/Search and Metadata/Search Settings` I turned off `Simple CJK handling`.
- Under `Custom Search Content Tab` I used the default of `-Any-` and under the Exclusion options left all but my two desired `content types` checked.
- Under `Administrator/Configuration/Search and Metadata/Search Settings` I clicked `re-index site`.
- I then flushed all caches and ran `cron` until the site was once again 100% indexed.

After all that I performed my tests again and everything was coming up as expected. Hopefully this can help others later in their testing.